# How to make echo work inside html content of an echo

Tags: php, user-interface

I am here in search for a new method. I have defined the value of `$SHOW_REALTIME_DATA_BUTTON_LABEL` in another php file like this:

```
english.php(file name)

define("SHOW_REALTIME_DATA_BUTTON_LABEL","Select realtime data");
```

...and I want to display that value in another file
inside the echo statement like this:

```
echo '<a  class="'.$class1.'" href="'.$link1.'"><span>'.$SHOW_REALTIME_DATA_BUTTON_LABEL.'</span></a> <br>';
```

In brief, I have to echo the value '**Select realtime data**' in between spans.

Comment: Not needed the $ symbol if you have defined something in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove `$` from it. This is what you should have:

```
echo '<a  class="'.$class1.'" href="'.$link1.'">
<span>'.SHOW_REALTIME_DATA_BUTTON_LABEL.'</span></a> <br>';
```

[See the docs for more info.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<span><?php echo SHOW_REALTIME_DATA_BUTTON_LABEL?></span>
```

Defined things not need $ symbol in php

Comment: Sorry I don't see the question changed

Comment: Well, he has just escape from php echo. not a big deal. +1

Answer (score 1):

Everybody is showing you the fish, but better learn about the [use of constants in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php):

```
<?php
define("CONSTANT", "Hello world.");
echo CONSTANT; // outputs "Hello world."
echo Constant; // outputs "Constant" and issues a notice.
?>
```

When you use **define** you are creating a constant, which is good to use when you have things that are constant. An example of predefined constant is the value of PI:

```
echo M_PI; // 3.1415926535898
```

These are things that are not changing during the execution of your script. Another good example is:

```
    define("MONTHS", 12); // months in year
    define("WEEK", 7); // days in weeek
```

You dont need to use a $ sign for constants, only for variables. And remember that the is recommended to use CAPITALS for constants but not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the bucks. PHP defines don't have a $ at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

this definitely should be

```
<a class="<?=$class1?>" href="<?=$link1?>">
  <span><?=SHOW_REALTIME_DATA_BUTTON_LABEL?></span>
</a><br>
```

However, I wouldn't use constants for the internationalization but rather arrays or [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php)
Also, a constant name looks oversized while words "show" and "label" unnecessary. `realtime_data_button` looks better to me